# Problems loading MOTODEV_Studio_for Android_2.1.0_Windows-x86

Tags: motorola-droid

I recently tried to install MotoDev and experienced a problem looking for Android SDK R10.  It kept complaining that it found r9.  I tried to reinstall r10 and ran into the Back/Next problem with the installer.  After many hours of frustration I finally figured it out but now motodev still didn't recognize r10.

So I took the apple approach, I uninstalled, JAVA SDK, Android SDK, Eclipse, and MotoDev.  I cleared off all remnants on the disk to start clean.

I Install each component clean in this order:

1. Java SDK (JDK-6u24-windows-i586)
2. Android SDK (installer-R10-windows)
   3.Android Compatibility package rev 1
   4.Third party Add-ons
       Google USB Driver package rev 4
       Google Market License package rev 1
       Google Market Billing Package rev 1
   5.Virtual Devices
       2.2 Api 8
       2.3.1   Api 9
       2.3.3   Api 10
       3.0 Api 11
3. Eclipse (eclipse-SDK-3.6.1-win32.zip)
   c:\eclipse
4. Eclipse android plugin

Everything worked OK........................

Then I reinstalled motodev

MotoDev (MOTODEV_Studio_for Android_2.1.0_Windows-x86)
    c:\Program Files\Motorola Mobility\MotoDev Studio for Android 2.1

And when I brought it up got an error saying it needed Android SDK 10 and found only SDK 9

SDK 9 is not on my system

I'm going back to Eclipse development environment until someone clears this up.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to see you were having problems.  The move from SDK r9 to r10 definitely had problems for all of us. We tried to make it as painless as possible, but it required that the move be done in a specific order. MOTODEV Studio 2.1 requires the ADT from SDK r10. There is no backward compatibility because some of the APIs inside the ADT plugins changed. So, MOTODEV Studio 2.0.1 works with SDK r9 and Studio 2.1.x and later work with SDK tools r10 and r11.

Eric